# How to redirect Win cmd output "live" and not wait

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cmd

1) I need to run an external program on Windows 7 in Python and redirect the "live" output(do not need STDERR) to a file call log.txt. Preferably append, not overwrite.
2) This external program will time to time log events into my output file, log.txt. 
3) I do NOT want my python script to wait above #1 and #2 happening. In other words, I want my python scrip to do #1 and #2 and return so I can do other things.

I have tried following with not much luck,
1) ' |& tee ~'
2) '>>'
3)

> with open(fileName,'w') as fout:
>       subprocess.call(command,stdout=fout)

All of the above attempts caused my code to wait. I need to somehow issue a child process and not wait for the return. 
Can anyone help me out with this please?

Below code does log first subprocess call. But after that it doesnt log anything from the sendCmd(). If I were to manually run pdSniffer.py it will log to the same Event.log file.

```
def startListner():
  fileName =getScriptPath() +r'\Script\allscripts\eventLog.txt'
  path =getScriptPath() +r'\Script\allscripts\pdSniffer.py 198.168.1.101 '
  winCMD='C:\\Python27\\python ' +path
  fout =open(fileName,'w')
  subprocess.Popen(winCMD, stdout=fout)
  Delay(2000)
  sendCmd()
  Delay(360000)

def sendCmd():
  path =getScriptPath() +r'\Script\allscripts\sendCreateEvent.py 192.168.1.100 1041 1143 0 4 0'  
  p =subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Python27\\python', path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) interface, which does not block unless you manually call `wait`:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=fout)
```

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'?

Comment: @usustarr `fout` should be a file object (i.e. `open(fileName,'w')`), rather than a string containing the filename.

Comment: Thank you. That issue was solved! But the log still doesnt update "Live". Meaning after the subprocess call, I have a 5 minutes delay, so that I can catch any incoming evens. But the only thing it logs is that the subprocess call stdout.

Comment: @usustarr That's probably an effect related to buffering of standard output; perhaps Windows has an equivalent of [`unbuffer(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) or related? You could also consider piping to Python using the other available features of `Popen` rather than going through a normal file on the filesystem.

Comment: @hexafraction, there's no direct equivalent to `unbuffer`. I've seen winpty used for this, though I question its reliability. (Windows doesn't have pty devices, so it works by attaching to a console and polling the screen buffer.) There's also `stdbuf` in Unix to hook into the C runtime at startup and override the default buffering. Windows has no equivalent to that either. It's up to each program to provide a command-line option or environment variable to override the default buffering. For Python, use `-u` or the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable.

Comment: I'm bit confused on how to use this. I'm new to Python. Could you please give me the code for me to try out?

Comment: @usustarr Once you open the process with stdout as a pipe (i.e. `stdout=PIPE`), you can perform `proc.stdout.read()` to read data from that pipe.